# Do very old people not use auxiliary do?

Tags: american-english, auxiliary-verbs, interrogatives

I just have looked of the following information.
Does the following sentence wrong?
"If you not got a job, what would you do?
"If you did not Have a job, What would you do? <=Is this very old fasion sentence?

Comment: The older form of "did not have" is "had not", not "not got".

Comment: Only people over the age of 250.

Comment: You didn't mean "If you've not got …", did you?

Comment: No, I meant "If you not got a....".

Comment: *If you didn't have a job, what would you do?* and *If you had no job, what would you do?* are equally correct, although the former is much more common than the latter (the auxiliary do).  I suspect the choice between the two is regional not age-based, but I don't have any evidence for that, so I can't really answer.

Comment: @snailboat : Would you please let me know more about 250 over years old?

Comment: @user1917217 http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26657/if-go-not-is-improper-why-mention-not-is-proper/29590#29590

Comment: @user1917217 "If you not got" is and was just wrong, far as I can tell, and has nothing to do with what you quoted. "Not" comes after the first verb, and "you" is not a verb. That's why I was trying to figure out if you were asking about something similar instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot omit the auxiliary *do* in a sentence like *If you did not have a job, what would you do?*  The proposed sentence *If you not got a job, what would you do?* is incorrect.

You can, however, **contract** the words *did* and *not* into the contraction *didn't*, to form the sentence *If you didn't have a job, what would you do?*

Contractions like *didn't* are very common in spoken English and informal writing.  In formal writing, they are more likely to be avoided (opinions vary on whether or not they are appropriate).

Using *did not* instead of *didn't* in casual speech would make it sound a little more formal and perhaps slightly old-fashioned, but not excessively so, in my opinion.  I think the passage you quote is an exaggeration.

Comment: Or if you want to emphasize the *not*: "I did **not** take the last piece of cake."

Comment: *If you had no job, what would you do?* is correct, and is roughly what the user is asking about (I assume the reference to didn't have a car is a reference to a question from a few days ago)

Comment: Usually as I know, If I want to emphasize something sentence, the sentence doesn't use contraction.

Comment: @Joe: True, but that construction works only in certain situations.  In the sentence *If you didn't have three children, what would you do?*, I don't see an easy way to rephrase without the auxiliary.

Comment: *If you had fewer than three children...* or *If you had no children*, depending on what you're trying to explain. In that case it's *more* likely to use that construct really - *If you didn't have three children* leaves it somewhat unclear whether you mean if you had some number other than three, or specifically none.

Comment: @JOE : Why would you not use auxiliary-do in your sentence?

Comment: I suppose the difference is the auxiliary do lets you negate the whole participle, ie, *If you didn't have a job* -> *If !(have a job)*, while *If you had no job* is *If have !(job)*, which is (subtly) different.

Comment: @user1917217 I would use auxiliary do.  However, I was pointing out there was a valid alternate construction.